# Find The Longest Word Sequence in Word Snake Game Problems

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

I was playing the game Word Snake and I was wandering if it is be possible to solve this game using an algorithm.

Here is the description of the game:

Given a bag (a set with possible repeating values) of phrases: S = {phrase<sub>1</sub>, phrase<sub>2</sub>, phrase<sub>3</sub>, ..., phrase<sub>N</sub>}

A snake is an ordered list of phrases from S such that, except for the first phrase, the first word in the phrase matches the last word in the previous phrase. Also, the phrase<sub>i (where 1 ≤ i ≤ N)</sub> can only be present once.

How to find the maximum length of all possible snakes?

Example: For `S = { 'A B' , 'B C' , 'B D' , 'C B' , 'C D'}`, the maximum length would be `4` because `['A B', 'B C', 'C B', 'B D']` is the longest snake.

Comment: It is an NP-hard problem, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I am not sure it is. The Decision problem (Finding if there is an optimal such path using all phrases) is definetly not NP-Hard.

Answer (score 2):

This likely can be solved by some variation of optmization problem of [Eulerian Path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Reduce the problem to a graph:

```
G = (V, E) where:
V = { all words }
E = {(word1, word2) | ​If there is a phrase word1, word2 }
```

In your example:

```
V = {A, B, C, D }
E = {(A,B), (B,C) (B,D), (C, B), (C, D) }
```

Now, Unfortunately, this instance of the problem is not an Eulerian Path, but if an Eulerian path existed - finding it would have got you the optimal solution. Example, if you add the phrase `'D C'`, the graph becomes eulerian, and indeed you can find the euler path:

`A -> B -> C -> B -> D -> C -> D`, which stands for `'A B', 'B C', 'C B', 'B D', 'D C', C D'`

The good news about Eulerian path - this problem can be solved efficiently and is Not NP Complete (unless P=NP).

Note: This solution is working out of the box to find if there is a sequence containing ALL phrases (and lets you find it easily). I am not familiar, and haven't studies the issue, if the optimization problem is substantially harder though.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I assumed phrase repetition is forbidden. If phrase repetition is allowed, one can check if any cycle is accessible from the starting phrase. If so, output infinity. Otherwise, proceed as in the DAG approach.

We can arrange the phrases into a graph, where each vertex is a phrase, and there exists a directed edge from `phraseA` to `phraseB` if and only if the last word from `phraseA` is the same as the first word from `phraseB`. Once we have constructed this graph, we want to find the longest path in this graph.

If the graph is acyclic, which means there exist no cycles, then it is possible to find the longest path by using a [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm on the same graph, but with edges of weight `-1`.

If, however, the graph contains cycles, which is the overwhelming majority of cases, the problem becomes [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), possibly apart from some other edge cases.

Notice, that your very simple example already contains a cycle: `'B C' -> 'C B' -> 'B C'`.

In conclusion, the only way you can hope to solve the problem is by iterating over all of the `n!` possibilities, where `n` is the size of `S`.

Comment: `If, however, the graph contains cycles, which is the overwhelming majority of cases, the problem becomes NP-hard, possibly apart from some other edge cases.` - Note that the reduction of the original problem becomes NP-Hard, not the problem itself though...

Comment: @amit you can reduce it the other way around by taking an arbitrary directed graph and interpreting each vertex as a word and each edge is a sentence.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Not sure it works though. Longest Path problem is looking for longest **simple** path only, while this problem clearly allows loops. (so a valid solution in this problem is not reflected back to a valid solution to longest path, which makes the reduction fail). The only restriction in original problem is using the same phrase only once, and in fact - finding a solution with ALL phrases is polynomial.

Comment: @amin *If* there is a solution that contains all phrases, then finding it is polynomial. It is a problem of finding an Eulerian path. However finding a maximal Eulerian subgraph is still hard. https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5746